# how to create a parallax.js's effect with parcel-bundler?

Tags: parcel, parallax.js

parallax plug is here    https://github.com/pixelcog/parallax.js

I was already installed  " npm install jquery ".

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: you can install parallax.js with `npm i --save jquery-parallax.js`